# My Perlin Noise function having too many dark spots, and little strips of white

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I created a Perlin noise function by loosely following a java tutorial in C#.
I then used Unity to visualize it (I don't think the issue is with unity, as their inbuilt func works perfectly)

The problem is that there are too many large dark spots. [Here is a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNAON.png)

[This is how I would like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R04m.png)

As you can see, it looks as if the points are not blending well.

Here is my code for the noise:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PerlinNoise
{
    public PerlinNoise()
    {
    }

    public double GetPixel(double x, double y)
    {
        int xint = (int)Math.Floor(x) & 255;
        int yint = (int)Math.Floor(y) & 255;    //gets what cube the input coords are


        int g1 = p[p[xint] + yint];
        int g2 = p[p[xint + 1] + yint];
        int g3 = p[p[xint] + yint + 1];
        int g4 = p[p[xint + 1] + yint + 1];     //gets the gradient vector's vaule on the permutation table

        double xdec = x - Math.Floor(x);
        double ydec = y - Math.Floor(y);    //gets the pixel inside the cube

        double d1 = grad(g1, xdec, ydec);
        double d2 = grad(g2, xdec - 1, ydec);
        double d3 = grad(g3, xdec, ydec - 1);
        double d4 = grad(g4, xdec - 1, ydec - 1);

        double u = fade(xdec);
        double v = fade(ydec);

        double x1Inter = lerp(u, d1, d2);
        double x2Inter = lerp(u, d3, d4);
        double yInter = lerp(v, x1Inter, x2Inter);

        return yInter;
    }

    private static double lerp(double amount, double left, double right)
    {
        return ((1 - amount) * left + amount * right);
    }

    private static double fade(double t)
    {
        return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
    }

    private static double grad(int hash, double x, double y)
    {
        switch (hash & 3)
        {
            case 0: return x + y;
            case 1: return -x + y;
            case 2: return x - y;
            case 3: return -x - y;
            default: return 0;
       }
   }

    private static readonly int[] p = { 151,160,137,91,90,15,
    131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,    
    190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
    88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
    77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
    102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
    135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
    5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
    223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
    129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
    251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
    49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
    138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180,151,160,137,91,90,15,
    131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
    190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
    88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
    77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
    102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
    135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
    5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
    223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
    129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
    251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
    49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
    138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180
    };

}
```

Here is the unity texture code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

// Create a texture and fill it with Perlin noise.
// Try varying the xOrg, yOrg and scale values in the inspector
// while in Play mode to see the effect they have on the noise.

public class TextureApply : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Width and height of the texture in pixels.
    public int pixWidth;
    public int pixHeight;

    // The origin of the sampled area in the plane.
    public float xOrg;
    public float yOrg;

    // The number of cycles of the basic noise pattern that are repeated
    // over the width and height of the texture.
    public float scale = 1.0F;

    private Texture2D noiseTex;
    private Color[] pix;
    private Renderer rend;

    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        // Set up the texture and a Color array to hold pixels during processing.
        noiseTex = new Texture2D(pixWidth, pixHeight);
        pix = new Color[noiseTex.width * noiseTex.height];
        rend.material.mainTexture = noiseTex;

        CalcNoise();
    }

    void CalcNoise()
    {
        // For each pixel in the texture...
        float y = 0.0F;

         while (y < noiseTex.height)
        {
            float x = 0.0F;
            while (x < noiseTex.width)
             {
                double xCoord = xOrg + x / noiseTex.width * scale;
                double yCoord = yOrg + y / noiseTex.height * scale;

                PerlinNoise perlin = new PerlinNoise();
                double sample = perlin.GetPixel(xCoord, yCoord);
            
                pix[(int)y * noiseTex.width + (int)x] = new Color((float)sample, (float)sample, (float)sample);
                x++;
            }
            y++;
        }

        // Copy the pixel data to the texture and load it into the GPU.
        noiseTex.SetPixels(pix);
        noiseTex.Apply();
    }

    void OnValidate()
    {
        CalcNoise();
    }
}
```

Above is just modified code from [docs.unity3d.com](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html)

I think the issue might be with the permutation table, instead of doing some convoluted way of doubling the number of values, I just copied and pasted it.

EDIT:
[This is a picture of what I'm getting when I change this to Simplex Noise][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfxNr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the gradient set being used. Directions (1, 1) point directly at diagonal neighbors. If those diagonal neighbors have (-1, -1), then they constructively interfere. Same for other corner pairs, and for when they point negative instead of positive at each other. EDIT: You can try `+x + ROOT2*y,  +ROOT2*x + y`, and all sign permutations thereof, to produce 8 gradients.

Also, even if you improve the gradients, you may have heard that Perlin is an older method for noise, which produces a lot of 45 and 90 degree bias. There aren't a lot of cases where I recommend it. If you want to implement noise as a programming exercise, that's great. But if you want to use noise in a project, I would either code or import a good 2D simplex implementation.

EDIT: See comments. I looked at the wrong image. Solution you need, is only `sample = sample * 0.5 + 0.5` to rescale the output so that the negative values don't all get cut off in the image.

Also if you want to convert your noise into a rudimentary simplex, you can do this:

1. Define constants `double F2 = 0.366025403784439` and `double G2 = -0.211324865405187`. These will be used below, to work with the triangular grid.
2. At the beginning of GetPixel(double x, double y) add `double s = (x + y) * F2;` `x += s; y += s;`. This will convert the coordinates which produce integers on a square grid, to coordinates which produce integers on a diagonally-compressed square grid which represents equilateral triangles.
3. After you define `xdec` and `ydec`, add `double t = (xdec + ydec) * G2;` `xdec += t; ydec += t;`. This will unskew these coordinates relative to the base of the compressed square, so that they can now be used for distance and gradients again.
4. Define doubles `xdec2 = xdec - 1 - G2;` `ydec2 = ydec - G2;`. Define `xdec3 = xdec - G2;` `ydec3 = ydec - 1 - G2;`. Define `xdec4 = xdec - 1 - 2*G2;` `ydec4 = ydec - 1 - 2*G2;`. You need this, because simply subtracting 1 doesn't work anymore to get the relative coordinates to the other four corners, because the corners aren't aligned with a square anymore. Now, any time you subtract 1 from *either* of the coordinates, you also need to subtract G2 from *both*. Thus, for #2 and #3 you subtract G2 once from each, and for #4 you subtract it twice (2*G2). You can re-derive this yourself by seeing what happens if you had already subtracted 1 from one or both of the coordinates, before calculating the previous step where you define `double t`.
5. Change d2, d3, d4 to use these values instead, like `d2 = grad(g2, xdec2, ydec2);`
6. Remove everything starting with `double u` and ending with `return yInter;`. Add `double value = 0;`. You will add stuff to this value.
7. Define `double a1 = 0.5 - xdec*xdec - ydec*ydec;` `double a2 = 0.5 - xdec2*xdec2 - ydec2*ydec2;` and the same pattern for a3 and a4. These functions represent circles around each triangle vertex, which stop at the triangle edges.
8. Add `if (a1 > 0) value += (a1 * a1) * (a1 * a1) * d1;` and the same for a2, a3, a4. These add a value to the noise inside each of those circles, based on the gradient and distance.
9. If you use the improved gradients I suggested for Perlin, add `return value * 38.283687591552734375;`. If you use the original ones, I think the right value to multiply by is `75.3929901123046875` but I'm not sure. It will be something close to that, though. Really, you probably want more gradients for simplex, but the 8 should make it look better than Perlin at least.

The noise will not look very good without the improved gradients. You will still see a lot of 45 degree bias. If you want to really improve the noise, here is my suggestion, with 24 gradients. You can find these gradients [here](https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/blob/beb35cb70cbf1ffa5a5a5ce2470eee00f977c182/java/OpenSimplex2F.java#L518). Use `99.83685446303647` as the value you multiply by at the end.

```
    private static double grad(int hash, double x, double y)
    {
        switch (hash % 24)
        {
            case 0:  return 0.130526192220052 * x +   0.99144486137381 * y;
            case 1:  return 0.38268343236509 * x +    0.923879532511287 * y;
            case 2:  return 0.608761429008721 * x +   0.793353340291235 * y;
            case 3:  return 0.793353340291235 * x +   0.608761429008721 * y;
            case 4:  return 0.923879532511287 * x +   0.38268343236509 * y;
            case 5:  return 0.99144486137381 * x +    0.130526192220051 * y;
            case 6:  return 0.99144486137381 * x +   -0.130526192220051 * y;
            case 7:  return 0.923879532511287 * x +  -0.38268343236509 * y;
            case 8:  return 0.793353340291235 * x +  -0.60876142900872 * y;
            case 9:  return 0.608761429008721 * x +  -0.793353340291235 * y;
            case 10: return 0.38268343236509 * x +   -0.923879532511287 * y;
            case 11: return 0.130526192220052 * x +  -0.99144486137381 * y;
            case 12: return -0.130526192220052 * x + -0.99144486137381 * y;
            case 13: return -0.38268343236509 * x +  -0.923879532511287 * y;
            case 14: return -0.608761429008721 * x + -0.793353340291235 * y;
            case 15: return -0.793353340291235 * x + -0.608761429008721 * y;
            case 16: return -0.923879532511287 * x + -0.38268343236509 * y;
            case 17: return -0.99144486137381 * x +  -0.130526192220052 * y;
            case 18: return -0.99144486137381 * x +   0.130526192220051 * y;
            case 19: return -0.923879532511287 * x +  0.38268343236509 * y;
            case 20: return -0.793353340291235 * x +  0.608761429008721 * y;
            case 21: return -0.608761429008721 * x +  0.793353340291235 * y;
            case 22: return -0.38268343236509 * x +   0.923879532511287 * y;
            case 23: return -0.130526192220052 * x +  0.99144486137381 * y;
            default: return 0;
       }
   }
```

Optional optimization: You only need one of a2/g2/xdec2/ydec2, a3/g3/xdec3/ydec3 at a time. If ydec > xdec then you can do a3/g3/xdec3/ydec3, otherwise a2/g2/xdec2/ydec2. Almost every tutorial and implementation out there will have this, but you don't need it to make the noise work.

Optional optimization #2: In step 8, you can pull in the definition of d1, and inside that you can pull in the definition of g1. That way, the definitions will only be computed when they're needed inside that conditional (if the compiler doesn't already catch that). `if (a1 > 0) value += (a1 * a1) * (a1 * a1) * grad(p[p[xint] + yint], xdec, ydec);` Then you can remove them from where they're originally computed.

Note: Some tutorials or implementations will use a positive G2, and flip the additions/subtractions of it. I find that it makes most sense to keep it negative, because then the unskew transform works exactly like the skew transform. But it's worthwhile to keep in mind.

Comment: Can you tell me where I need to do the changes, I'm just starting to learn this stuff.

Also thanks for letting me know about simplex noise (this will be useful, as it is a project for school and having more options is good), but for now I'm just experimenting.

Comment: IMO it's problematic if a school is teaching Perlin noise, at least if it's not in light of emphasis on better alternatives. Nonetheless, in your grad statement, change hash & 3 to hash & 7 because you have 8 gradients now.

`case 0: return + x + ROOT2*y;`
`case 1: return + ROOT2 * x + y;`

and define cases 2-7 for the rest of the sign permutations +-, -+, and --

Then define a constant float ROOT2=1.4142135623730951f; which is the square root of 2. These gradient directions form a perfect octagon, and the square root of 2 is needed for that.

Comment: Also if you want, you can multiply your output by 0.579106986522674560546875f. I wrote a program a while back to find this. It will make the output range exactly -1 to 1.

Comment: Also I just re-read your post. I had confused the desired photo, with the one you're getting. My mistake. Your only problem is that the output range is both negative and positive (centered on zero), while the way you render it can only handle positives. The solution to your problem is to do `sample = sample * 0.5 + 0.5;` to rescale what would be a range of -1 to 1, to a range of 0 to 1. The stuff I sent about gradients is just a further improvement.

Comment: If you don't *need* to code the noise yourself, you can import `Unity.Mathematics` and use `Unity.Mathematics.noise.snoise(float2)` for 2D simplex.

Comment: I edited my original post to clarify the error, and with more info about simplex.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help! That fixed the Perlin noise!

I followed your steps to make the simplex noise, and i doesn't seem to work. I noticed you didn't use the grad() func in any way. I don't know simplex noise well enough to work out where to use it, so if you could help, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Also, i'll be sure to mention you in my coursework for this project :))

Comment: The result I was getting, was a bunch of black dots, but then I changed g1,g2... to d1,d2... in the last IF statements. This created some sort of noise, but now I'm getting the hard edges of the triangles, I think this is because the lerp() or fade() functions are not being used and its giving a result like Perlin noise does when it uses a linear gradient.

Comment: I edited my first post with a picture of the noise.

Comment: I found two mistakes in my original steps, and edited the post. Inserted missing step 5, and corrected step 8 (formerly step 7) to use g1-4 rather than d1-4.

Note that this won't look very good with the existing grad() function. Changing it to the 8 gradients does improve it, but I edited the post with what I would do which would really improve the appearance.

Comment: You don't need fade/lerp, because that's what a1/a2/a3/a4 and (a * a) * (a * a) accomplish.

Comment: This is **AMAZING** help, Thank you so much. If you have time, can you show me the implementation of the optimization 1, and any other optimizations, you might know.

Comment: Remove the parts for g3/d3/a3/xdec3/ydec3, leaving only d2/... You want to modify d2/... so that they reflect what either d2/... or d3/... was, depending on which you need. If you didn't do optimization 2, make sure you at least move g1/g2/g4 to after the xdec/ydec definition because the following step depends on it. Define `int i = ydec > xdec ? 0 : 1;` and `int j = 1 - i;` You'll see that one of these is always zero, and the other is always 1. It represents which triangle you're in on the compressed square. It doesn't matter if this is before or after the `+= t` part.

Comment: You can insert i,j into the xdec2 and ydec2 definitions in place of 1, so that it refers to the one you need, i.e. `xdec2 = xdec - i - G2;` `ydec2 = ydec - j - G2;` Now, update g2 like `g2 = p[p[xint + i] + yint + j]` so that it also represents the correct value. Then, g2, a2 and anything else involving xdec2/ydec2/g2 should work properly. Then finally, you might choose to rename g4/d4/a4/xdec4/ydec4 to g3/d3/a3/xdec3/ydec3 since you removed what once was g3/d3/a3/xdec3/ydec3.

Comment: There are always other optimizations you can do if you run into performance issues, such as pre-computing the "% 24" modulo in a copy of the perm table, finding different ways to compute i and j, baking the 99.8368 constant directly into the gradient multipliers, and converting the switch statement to a lookup table to see if it's faster. But using 2D noise for a 2D heightmap or texture is generally very fast already, and the two optimizations in the main body of my answer are probably the biggest ones anyway.

Comment: It's also possible to use lookup tables and loops as seen here: https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/blob/beb35cb70cbf1ffa5a5a5ce2470eee00f977c182/java/OpenSimplex2F.java#L92 but that's a step even further, and it may be possible that a very optimized non-lookup/loop implementation is faster than this.

Comment: You can also use a conditional and just do one or the other. That actually ended up being the fastest way I found short of using a lookup table. https://github.com/Auburn/FastNoise/blob/08cfd2e2df8cd33c6caab11752137875cc0efb6b/CSharp/FastNoiseLite.cs#L1024